# Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Packs version x86 or x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-office, 32-bit

I have just installed Windows 7 Ultimate **x64** and Microsoft Office 2010 Professionall Plus **x86** (i.e. the 32-bit **NOT** the 64-bit Office version as recommended by Microsoft).

Now I also want to install [Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Packs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17062) .

Should I install the Filter Packs **64-bit version** because Windows is 64-bit

**OR**

the Filter Packs **32-bit version** becasue Office is 32-bit?